# How to configure logback db appender in jbossAS7

Tags: jboss7.x, logback

I am using Jboss AS7 and i performed the logs in the file. Now i want to migrate from file to database using logback. How to configure standalone.xml for logback?

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a specific logger implementation that supports logging to database out of the box. What you need is a custom log handler.

There is a custom log handler implementation for reference [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CustomLogHandlersOn701)
https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CustomLogHandlersOn701

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. Actually what my question is can i use logback framework for logging in jboss..?  or else need to use only the default jboss logging framework?

Comment: Not. You are not forced to use Out of the box implementation. You can extend the logging framework and the URL I shared is one of them.

Comment: hi, i followed the steps same as the link. But i'm facing this exception..           Failed to configure handler DB on Logger '' in context org.jboss.logmanager.LogContext@170bea5: Handler DB has no class name  can you please help me?

Comment: Can you share the entire exception stack trace?

Comment: Exception posted below. Please answer me..?

Comment: Is there any configuration change in the logging.properties filee?